# SetErrorMode has no effect?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp, messagebox

I call

```
"SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX | SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);"
```

before loading a DLL. Nevertheless a windows message pops up

> "This application has failed to start
>   because blabla.dll was not found...".

Why does that happen? I thought that was what SetErrorMode was supposed to prevent?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `SetErrorMode` is probably never executed - if you statically link to the DLL, it will be loaded along with the executable. The message you see is popped by the operating system, and not by your code. If you want control over the load of the DLL, you should load it using [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - but then using exported functions is a bit harder.

You can create your own loader (a different executable), which will make sure all DLLs are available, and then run the main executable. But that might be an overkill...

Comment: Um, I think there's a little misunderstanding here. Sorry for not having been clearer. Actually the DLL is loaded via LoadLibrary. And the SetErrorMode is executed before with 100% certainty. But the then the loading of another DLL (used by the DLL I load) fails...

Comment: Would it be possible that setting the error mode is somehow disabled by previously executed code? E.g. the error mode has been set before by another part of the application, and now I can't set it to something different?

Comment: @Hans, this is probably what's happening. Normally, SetErrorMode successfully suppresses LoadLibrary error notifications. Try calling `GetErrorMode` right after the failure, to see what's its current value. If it had changed, there's your problem. One lesson to learn if you develop a DLL - always consider the possibility someone has called SetErrorMode before, and consider masking the existing value according to your need... If this is the case, you might have to manually check the existence of the required DLLs before you LoadLibrary.

Comment: Well, it seems as if the error mode is set correctly. All flags are set BEFORE and AFTER the DLL is loaded. So the problem must lie somewhere else... any more ideas? Thanks :-)

Comment: @Hans, Someone might still be setting the error mode in the loaded DLL, and then restoring it before it returns to your code. Another option is that the DLL is starting a new process, which is the actual origin of the message (error mode is per process). You can identify the latter using ProcExp (check when message is popped). To identify the former you'll need to do some hacking - hook SetErrorMode, find out where the mode value is stored in memory or so. It's not going to be pretty...